# Asynchronous API Calls in Python/Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, asynchronous, async-await

Attempting to use asynchronous programming for multiple API calls when loading up a website via Flask. Running in python 3. Familiar how to do this with async/await outside of python but haven't been able to get progress in this instance.

apis.py

```
def getAPI(var):
    try:
        cnxn = p.connnect(' stuff here ')
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(" thing im calling ")
        data1 = cursor.fetchall()
    except:
        { stuff to do if my db is down }

    {{ repeat above for several other calls setting data2, 3, 4... etc }}

    return data1, data2, data3....
```

routes.py

```
from {location} import getAPI 

@app.route('/manual', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def manual():
     data1, data2, data3... = getAPI(var)
```

This works as expected, however with all the calls there is a delay when  loading the page that I would like to get rid of. Have tried aiohttp and asyncio, neither had much progress with. Think how I was trying to use was incorrect. Not overly familiar with either library and all I have found has yet to lead me to the answer.

Some of my errors (apis.py):

```
Invalid syntax
SyntaxError: cannot assign to await expression
```

Or on routes.py

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable coroutine object
```

Any thoughts/advice is appreciated